# does TelephonyManager.getCellLocation() work on lte and wcdma phones?

Tags: android

I'm using

```
    cellLocation=telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
    if(cellLocation instanceof  GsmCellLocation) {
    //get cid
    }else if(cellLocation instanceof  CDMACellLocation){
    //get cid
    }
```

to get cell info for gsm and cdma.

I'm not sure what will happen on lte and wcdma phones? Since I have a 3G phone so I could only make sure that it work for 3G network.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question?